# Rieman integrable on $R=[0,2]\times[0,4]$

Tags: real-analysis

I have $R=[0,2]\times[0,4]$ and $f:R\to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$f(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
3,  & \text{if } x,y \quad rational \\
2, & \text{if } x \quad rational \quad and \quad y \quad irrational \\
1, & \text{if } y \quad rational \quad and \quad x \quad irrational \\
0, & \text{if } x,y \quad irrational
\end{cases}$$

isn't f Rieman-integrable on R?

Comment: Is it continuous anywhere? Hint: is $\mathbb{Q}^2$ dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$? What about $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$?

Comment: Consider a fixed x, either rational or irrational. Is f integrable wrt y along this strip?